# VMWare Datastore Availability Between Hosts

Tags: vmware-vcenter, datastore

I'm having trouble getting my datastores to be visible to all hosts in my cluster. I could swear I've done everything right, but I clearly didn't, because I still can't get these datastores accessible from other hosts. The end goal is to get DRS set up in the cluster, largely because I have most of my storage on one or two hosts, but the compute power spread all over the cluster.

**Environment:**

- 4 VM Hosts in a cluster, each with local storage that I want to make available to the other hosts
- All hosts and VMs connected via distributed switch on vCenter server
- an iSCSI device teamed with the uplink on each host
- all port groups on the VDS are set to allow all kinds of funky traffic, for testing purposes
- vMotion is configured and working properly
- vCenter 6.0
- ESXi 6.0 on all hosts

I'm not a VMWare expert, and I feel I've missed something basic, but anyone who's read it I'm sure would agree with me that the VMWare documentation *sucks*.

Comment: `largely because I have most of my storage on one or two hosts`... Do you only have local storage, or is there also a SAN (iSCSI or FC) in the picture.

Comment: Local storage only

Comment: Yeah.. it doesn't work quite that simply. Depending on your drive configuration and license level, you *might* be able to use VMware's [VSAN](http://www.vmware.com/ca/en/products/virtual-san), but even that won't be perfect.

Comment: Well drat. That was not made clear in the documentation I've read. Thanks for the clarity!

Answer (score 0):

•4 VM Hosts in a cluster - That doesn't tell us anything about your storage and doesn't help us determine what the problem is.

•All hosts and VMs connected via distributed switch on vCenter server - This also isn't related to your storage.

•an iSCSI device teamed with the uplink on each host - How about giving us a lot more details about this?

•all port groups on the VDS are set to allow all kinds of funky traffic, for testing purposes - Again, not related to storage.

•vMotion is configured and working properly - vMotion doesn't require any configuration as far as I remember. You enable it, but there isn't any actual configuration, so I'm not sure what you mean by this statement.

•vCenter 6.0 - Good to know. Thanks for including this information.

•ESXi 6.0 on all hosts - Good to know. Thanks for including this information.

So, can you give us a lot more detail on your storage? What kind of storage? How do the hosts connect to the storage? Etc., etc.

Comment: All local storage on each host, through vCenter I was under the impression I should be able to make local disks available to all hosts on the cluster. Other hosts should be connecting to it via the VDS (hence why its configuration is relevant)

Comment: What gave you that impression?

Comment: The vDS isn't related to the host storage. You can do vMotion without shared storage but you can't do HA or DRS (AFAIK) without shared storage. You need to look into VSAN or the like.